# custom ListView inside Update panel not refreshing

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to solve this problem.
I have an Accordion inside an UpdatePanel. Inside the Accordion control I dinamically create at most four AccordionPanes, each with a custom ListView that shows some image previews fetched from a database. Each preview is composed by a 160x120 ImageButton. When the user clicks on one of these buttons a popup is opened with the image at real size (by a Seadragon control); he can now rotate the image and save it back to the database. Now, after saving the image, I close the popup and submit a postback by generating a click event on a hidden button inside the UpdatePanel containing the Accordion, but even if I can step through the hidden button event code, the refresh doesn't take place. The hidden button was the last (and most effective) solution I've tried, without success. What am I missing ? (The absolute best solution would be refresh the only image that changed, because sometimes the ListView contains several previews).

This is the

```
    <div>
    <table class="style8">
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="usersPanel" runat="server" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <cc1:c1treeview ID="tvUsers" runat="server" 
                            onselectednodeschanged="tvUsers_SelectedNodesChanged" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            onnodecheckchanged="tvUsers_SelectedNodesChanged">
                        </cc1:c1treeview>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="imagesPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="hiddenImageRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" 
                    style="display:none;" onclick="hiddenImageRefresh_Click" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="accImages" runat="server" >
                        </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the code contained in the hidden button click event, code, that regularly runs when the popup closes. It simply extracts a user code (promo) and rebind the data (LoadImages)

```
    protected void hiddenImageRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string promo = "";

        if(Session[SessionVariables.CurrentPromoter] != null)
            promo = Session[SessionVariables.CurrentPromoter].ToString();

        LoadImages(promo, ddlImageType.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: How are you triggering the button click? put break point in code-behind `hiddenImageRefresh_Click` method and check whether you receive control in side or not.

Comment: The button click is triggered by a client script in the popup. Below is the code-behin of the save button :

Comment: protected void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveImage();

    ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
csm.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "closeScript", "closePopup(true);", true);
  }

Comment: can you show us the button click javascript, there would be issue. are you getting breakpoint at server side?

Comment: This is the javascript called by the client script : '            function closePopup(refreshParent)
            {
             if (refreshParent != null) {
              var bRefresh = window.opener.document.getElementById('hiddenImageRefresh');

              if (bRefresh == null)
               alert('Tag di refresh non trovato !');
              else
               bRefresh.click();
             }

                window.close();
            }'. The code in code-behind event hiddenImageRefresh_Click gets called, and all the control's values are in place (i.e. ddlImageType.SelectedValue).

Comment: Sometimes returning on the project after a few days lead me to some kind of solution, but nothing. Could it be related to the browser's cache ? The entire server code is called, including the databinding of the elements of the listview, but the image isn't refreshed until I press F5 to force the page reload. My customer has used this workaround, but is asking me for a more elegant solution. The images are loaded inside the image button via a service, and when the image is rotated it only changes inside the database, not in the ImageButton link to the service.

Comment: Its clearly browser cache issue. Show me where you setting sources for accordion images, I hope you're doing that in `LoadImages`, if it is show me the definition of `LoadImages` method.

Comment: Yes. Inside LoadImages I've the databinding of the listview (contained in the accordion panes) that holds the ImageButtons. In the DataBinding event of each ImageButton there's this assignment : img.ImageUrl = "../Handlers/ImageLoader.ashx?id=" + ... (some parameters here). I succeeded in having the images refreshed, moving outside the Accordion's UpdatePanel the hidden button I'm using to force the refresh, so this could be an acceptable behavior of the app for my customer, but better if I could refresh only the changed item...

Comment: You can do that, I hope the image id is the key for imageLoader.ashx handler right? show me the parameters you're setting in querystring for `img.ImageUrl = "../Handlers/ImageLoader.ashx?id=params"`

Comment: The compete URL is `img.ImageUrl = "../Handlers/ImageLoader.ashx?id=" + dImgTag.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "&promo=" + riga["PROMOTER"].ToString() + "&pv=" + riga["PV"].ToString()` , where the most important parameter is the image timestamp, already SQL formatted, and the code (promo=...) of the user that took the photo (just in case you have two users taking a photo in the exact moment...). I was thinking to create at runtime, in the ItemTtemplate, an UpdatePanel for each ImageButton, but I don't know if this technique introduces too much overhead.

Comment: That looks good! Timestamp id definitely force to reload/refresh images from server. Now you should focus on refreshing only the edited image instead of all images on `closePopup`.I'm going to add the answer for this approach

Answer (score 0):

Steps to refresh only updated image

Step#1: in JavaScript

```
//Take one global variable
var selectedImageId="";
```

Step#2: in JavaScript

```
//set above var with image id, When user clicks on the ImageButton, which is inside openPopup function
selectedImageId = this.id;
```

Step#3: in Code-Behind

```
protected void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //SaveImage();

    #region here get the imageUrl that needs to be updated and send as parameter in closePopup js function

    var timeStamp = dImgTag.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff") ;
    var promoter = riga["PROMOTER"].ToString();
    var pv = riga["PV"].ToString();
    var imageUrl = string.Format("../Handlers/ImageLoader.ashx?id={0}&promo={1}&pv={2}", timeStamp, promoter, pv);

    #endregion

    ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
    csm.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "closeScript", "closePopup(true,'"+ imageUrl +"');", true);
}
```

Step#4: in JavaScript

```
function closePopup(refreshParent, imageUrl) {
    if (refreshParent) {
        //get the selectedImage and set the source with new url 
        var selectedImage = window.opener.document.getElementById(selectedImageId);
        selectedImage.src = imageUrl;
    }
    window.close();
}
```